# Magento changing login message

Tags: magento

In Magento I have found the code that displays **Welcome guest, please sign in**. What i'd like to do is have **Log in / Sign up** display if they're not logged in and then **My Account** text display once they're logged in.

I looks like the checks if they're logged in or not...

```
<p class="welcome-msg">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl();?>customer/account/login/">please sign in</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do this, is using XML (always use local.xml)

You can use `<customer_logged_out>` and `<customer_logged_in>` handler in  your theme's local.xml.
Use the handler, get the correct reference and you can modify anything for LOGGED IN VS LOGGED OUT users.

example, for logged out users removing the links in the toplink in the header area.

```
<customer_logged_out>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
                <url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/>
            </action>
        </reference>
</customer_logged_out>

<customer_logged_in>
        <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
            <url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/>
        </action>
        </reference>
<!-- similarly, get the reference and change for logged in -->
</customer_logged_in>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use:

> (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())

to check if customer is logged in or not and display your Log-in, Log-out, My Account accordingly. But that might not go well if you have cache enabled. In case you use caching on your site, you can either:

- set the whole header block to never get cached (depend on caching module that you use so I can't give you specific instruction)
- use cookie (my choice): set a cookie to determine if log-in state. Then have a simple javascript function to hide log-out and My account link if the cookie is not set and vice versa.

Let me know how you go.